# Regular Expression (preg_match)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

This is the not working code:

```
<?php
$matchWith = "  http://videosite.com/ID123 ";
preg_match_all('/\S\/videosite\.com\/(\w+)\S/i', $matchWith, $matches);  
foreach($matches[1] as $value)
{  
    print '<a href="http://videosite.com/'.$value.'">Hyperlink</a>';        
}  
?>
```

What I want is that it should not display the link if it has a whitespace before or after.
So now it should display nothing. But it still displays the link.

Comment: according to ur question if it matches the reg exp it should n't show anything and you are doing just the opposite. Print if there is white space in start and end. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can also match ID12, because 3 is not an space, and the / of http:/ is not a space. You can try:

```
preg_match_all('/^\S*\/videosite\.com\/(\w+)\S*$/i', $matchWith, $matches);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

So, you don't want it to display if there's whitespaces.  Something like this should work, didn't test.

```
preg_match_all('/^\S+?videosite\.com\/(\w+)\S+?$/i', $matchWith, $matches);
```

Comment: Awesome. Just the answer I was looking for. But there is another problem. If (in the link) the ID is ID123 it only shows ID12. Thanks

Comment: Should be: /\s*\/videosite\.com\/(\w+)\s*/i.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. It works:

```
if (preg_match('%^\S*?/videosite\.com/(\w+)(?!\S+)$%i', $subject, $regs)) {
    #$result = $regs[0];
}
```

But i am positive that after I post this, you will update your question :)

**Explanation:**

```
"
^            # Assert position at the beginning of the string
\S           # Match a single character that is a “non-whitespace character”
   *?           # Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
\/           # Match the character “/” literally
videosite    # Match the characters “videosite” literally
\.           # Match the character “.” literally
com          # Match the characters “com” literally
\/           # Match the character “/” literally
(            # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \w           # Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
      +            # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
(?!          # Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)
   \S           # Match a single character that is a “non-whitespace character”
      +            # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
\$            # Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
"
```

Comment: What an awesome answer! unbelievable! However I am a really stupid noob and cant integrate this code into my code. But another code worked but still thank you, you guys are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be simpler to use this regex:

```
'/^http:\/\/videosite\.com\/(\w+)$/i'
```

I believe you are referring to the white space before `http`, and the white space after the directory.  So, you should use the `^` character to indicate that the string must start with http, and use the `$` character at the end to indicate that the string must end with a word character.